# Visual Studio 2010 SP1 and Changes to the .NET Framework

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

Does Visual Studio SP1 install any updates to the .NET Framework (eg. .NET 4 SP1)?

I ask because I'm assuming that if this is the case I'll need to make sure the servers have a matching version of the framework installed prior to my next deployment.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the link to the [msdn article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983509) which explains everything that Visual Studio 2010 SP1 touches.

Comment: WOW, that is a huge list of changes. I can't wait to get this installed!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there seems to be some updates to the .NET Framework. The new build number is  4.0.30319.225 (GDR). The RTM version of .NET 4.0 on my machine is 4.0.30319. Not much difference in build numbers here.

Here's the link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2468871