# visual studio 2010 sp1 source server support

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I am trying to step into the .NET4 source code.

I have recently installed SP1 for VS2010.

I cannot get this to work. After reading articles such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248281/visual-studio-2010-sp1-and-changes-to-the-net-framework) I'm assuming its because the source symbols VS is downloading do not match the version of the framework I have installed. Can someone confirm this?

Secondly, I downloaded the .NET4 source and tried to manually load the pdb's from the module window.

[image]

however for all possible selections (3) I get this error:

[image]

If the SP1 is the cause of my woes, I don't want to revert to non-SP1. **Does source debugging work in SP1? If Yes where am I going wrong?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asked this question on the [ozdotnet Users Forum](http://prdlxvm0001.codify.net/mailman/listinfo/ozdotnet) after not receiving a response here.  David Kean from Microsoft was kind enough to respond:

> We likely have yet to publish the symbols for the .NET Framework update that was included in SP1. It usually takes a few weeks to a couple of months for this happen. I'll see internally what the status of this is.

and

> Okay I asked internally. We plan on updating the external symbols in the coming month – they take a while after a release to be published.